# How to get String from setOnItemSelectedListener method?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-spinner, android-button

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to get a String from spinner. I've made some research but I couldn't find anything useful. Without trying to get String the code is working properly. This is the code which is working:

```
assert staticSpinner2 != null;
    staticSpinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String spinnerLanguage2 = staticSpinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        public String getSpin(String spinnerLanguage2) {
            return spinnerLanguage2;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

I tried to use a getter method as follows where I didn't get any errors:

```
assert staticSpinner2 != null;
    staticSpinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String spinnerLanguage2 = staticSpinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        public String getSpinnerString(String spinnerLanguage2) {
            return spinnerLanguage2;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

I'm trying to set this String to a text view using:

```
assert staticSpinner2 != null;
    staticSpinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String spinnerLanguage2 = staticSpinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        public String getSpinnerString(String spinnerLanguage2) {
            return spinnerLanguage2;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    MainActivityClassName AnObject = new MainActivityClassName();
    text.setText(AnObject.getSpinnerString());
```

Where I get an error saying "cannot resolve method getSpin()". I do realise I'm not passing any parameters to the method but I don't know how I can do it here. I appreciate any help or any other advice to solve the problem in a different way. Thanks in advance.

This is the full code if that helps:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    // spinner 1
    final Spinner staticSpinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter1 = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.lang,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    staticAdapter1
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    staticSpinner1.setAdapter(staticAdapter1);



    // spinner 2
    final Spinner staticSpinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    staticSpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            String spinnerLanguage = staticSpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();


            switch (spinnerLanguage) {
                case "Afrikaans":
                    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapterAF = ArrayAdapter
                            .createFromResource(getBaseContext(), R.array.af,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                    staticAdapterAF
                            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                    staticSpinner2.setAdapter(staticAdapterAF);
                    break;
                case "French":
                    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapterFR = ArrayAdapter
                            .createFromResource(getBaseContext(), R.array.fr,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                    staticAdapterFR
                            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                    staticSpinner2.setAdapter(staticAdapterFR);
                    break;
                case "English":
                    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapterEN = ArrayAdapter
                            .createFromResource(getBaseContext(), R.array.en,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                    staticAdapterEN
                            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                    staticSpinner2.setAdapter(staticAdapterEN);
                    break;
                case "Turkish":
                    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapterTR = ArrayAdapter
                            .createFromResource(getBaseContext(), R.array.tr,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                    staticAdapterTR
                            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                    staticSpinner2.setAdapter(staticAdapterTR);
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

    });


    assert staticSpinner2 != null;
    staticSpinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String spinnerLanguage2 = staticSpinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();


        }

        public String getSpin(String spinnerLanguage2) {
            return spinnerLanguage2;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    MainActivity AnObject = new MainActivity();
    text.setText(AnObject.getSpinnerString());

}
```

}

Comment: Try this parent.getItemAtPosition(position) in onItemSelected Refer here for more:- http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-with-spinner/

Comment: It produced the same error. I found tutorials like this one. However, they all do their tasks inside the onItemSelected method. What I need to do is to extract the string out of the method.

Comment: pass this value to a method then do what u want to do

Comment: I'm going to put it inside a url to perform a google search.

Comment: Give a try otherwise search what problem you facing and if not found then post here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
String selectedText = null;

staticSpinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        selectedText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Now you can use the `selectedText` variable to pass on to whatever method you want. But, keep in mind, unless you select something in the spinner, it's value would be `null`.

Comment: When I did that Android Studio forced me to make selectedText a final String array. I tried it I don't get any errors know but the TextView has disappeared.

Comment: Can you post your complete code? Where's TextView coming from now?

Comment: What's `MainActivityClassName` ?

Comment: Sorry I meant MainActivity, still got the same error though.

Comment: Why do you need an object of `MainActivity` inside `MainActivity` ? I am not able to understand your workflow. What is your desired behavior when this activity gets launched.

Comment: I was trying to call the getSpin method through object reference. I am trying to set the value of the spinner's selected item to a TextView just to see if I can get strings from the second spinner which I can't.

Comment: I defined the variable outside the onCreate method, used your code and it worked. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

If you really have to use it outer, you can do this :

```
 public void setTextView(String text){
        text.setText(text);
 }
```

and call this method inside your onItemSelected:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     setTextView(staticSpinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
```

Comment: This is working fine but what I actually need to do is to extract the string from onItemSelected method then I'm going to pass it to another main class method. I added setText here for simplicity.

Comment: Calling a external method like setTextView is a way to extract your String. Inside the setTextView you are on MainClass scope, and then, you can pass your String to any class you want.

Answer (score 2):

Having read that piece of code, why don't you extract "spinnerLanguage2" to your main class and then access it from there? Assigning the value inside the OnItemSelected method.

EDIT: 
My previous answer is wrong. Try to implement an interface in order to communicate with the other class. Thus, calling a method of that interface you can pass the value. I give you a link with this (It explains it for fragments, but yo can communicate your classes too):

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Can you please provide some code ti justify your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I have read it wrong, forget the previous answer. Maybe setting the text inside OnItemSelected Method would be the solution, thus you can control the textview whenever spinner changes.

Comment: I know I can set the text inside the onItemSelected method. What I really need to do is to extract the string outside the method. I used setText here for simplicity.

Comment: I didn't know that you use it in a separated class, take a look to my edited comment.